# Youtube API to get viewCount only works locally

Tags: php, api, youtube

I've just started using the API v3 to get individual videos viewCounts. But the code I'm using only works on my local sites and doesn't work at all as soon as I upload. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$vId = '1URvDyzh8uI';
$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id=$vId&key={myAPIkey}");
$video =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($video['items'] as $vidCount) {
$vCount= $vidCount['statistics']['viewCount']; 
}
echo $vCount;
?>
```

Am i missing something to make it work on live sites? I've looked into authentication being a possible problem, but have tried and failed in using it. Any helped would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Maybe `file_get_contents` is disabled on your live machine? (some hosts do this).

Comment: Check to make sure the API key you're using is valid for the host you're accessing from.

Comment: Thanks Halcyon! that was the issue. just set "allow_url_fopen" to On and its working now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Halcyon helped with his comment. Just change "allow_url_fopen" to On in the php.ini and it works!